# What does the suffix “-saurus” mean?

Tags: meaning, suffixes, latin

Is it the same meaning in *tyrannosaurus* as in *thesaurus*?

I really can’t imagine what those two words could possibly have in common!

Comment: It should be noted that the "-saurus" suffix is more than occasionally used with a tongue-in-cheek intent to construct a neologism with the implication of "terrible" or "prehistoric" or some such.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The two etymologies are different.

In *thesaurus*, the *-saurus* isn’t a suffix. It’s part of the word. The word actually comes from the Greek word *thēsaurós*, which means treasure or treasury.

In *tyrannosaurus*, the origin is from the Greek words *turannos*, which means tyrant, plus the word *sauros*, which means lizard.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. But why do I feel somehow disappointed? Think I wanted "thesaurus" to be something to do with dinosaurs.

Comment: Ah! The disappointment of truth!

Comment: Note that the etymology of Greek *thêsauros* is unknown according to Hofmann; the etymology of Greek *sauros/saura* is not explained in Hofmann but might be available elsewhere—if only the damned Leiden site would work that has Frisk's dictionary.

Comment: @Urbycoz [This thesaurus](http://shirt.woot.com/Blog/ViewEntry.aspx?Id=17350) *does* have something to do with dinosaurs :)

Comment: @Urbycoz Is there a thesaurus that does not contain "dinosaur"?

Comment: @Urbycoz Now I have all these mental pictures of the "Tyranno-thesaurus" chomping on words! If I ever teach kids of the appropriate age again, I'll have to make up some appropriate illustrations!

Answer (score 9):

They have different origins:

> **thesaurus** ORIGIN late 16th cent.: via Latin from Greek thēsauros ‘storehouse, treasure.’ The original sense [dictionary or encyclopedia] was narrowed to the current meaning by the publication of Roget's Thesaurus of English Words and Phrases (1852).
>
> **tyrannosaurus** ORIGIN modern Latin, from Greek turannos ‘tyrant’ + sauros ‘lizard,’ on the pattern of dinosaur.

From NOAD.

So, obviously, they do not have the same meanings. Although some people do like to make jokes about this. Cf. [What's a big-vocabulary word for someone with a big vocabulary?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/whats-a-big-vocabulary-word-for-someone-with-a-big-vocabulary/12803#12803)

Comment: Ahah nice quote...  :D

Comment: Oh dear, oh dear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You figured me out.

Comment: Don't hide your light under a bushel, as they say! Anyway, the world would be a poorer place if that one got lost.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesaurus), *thesaurus* derived from Latin and meant “treasure store”.  So assuming the first half of the word is treasure, then saurus must mean store presumably.

Contrarily, *[tyrannosaurus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannosaurus)* derived from the roots *tyrannos* and *sauros* from Greek, which meant “tyrant lizard”.

Therefore, since one derives from Latin and the other from Greek, I would assume the similarities in the roots are purely coincidental.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb, but I can't see why this has been marked down. Seems correct to me.

Comment: While I did not personally mark it down, I can see the argument. The latin root of *thesaurus* is derived from greek, which invalidates the concluding paragraph. Also, any answer which includes the words "assuming" and "presumably" is suspect. The first paragraph is vague and not properly researched. Linguistically, there's no reason to assume the first half of *thesaurus* means "treasure" and the second half "store". My understanding is that *thēsauros* is synonymous with *hoard*.

Comment: Although I didn't vote down this answer, if I could I would have voted down the remark "Thank you for using your brain."

Comment: Thesaurus derived from Latin, and the Romans derived it from Greek, so technically we're both right.  If you want to mark it down, that's your choice, though I don't think there's any risk that my answer might accidentally get considered correct.  The little number to the left of my answer and its position on the page made sure of that.

Comment: "Thank you for using your brain." I don't know, sounds dangerous. Too many people using their brains, the next thing you know, they start questioning the Established Order. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in another comment, one interpretation of the Greek word *thesaurus* is "hoard". That interpretation made me think of "dragon's hoard". If saurus = lizard = dragon, that could be the link between the *-saurus-* root and *thesaurus*. *Saurus* is the dragon/lizard, and *thesaurus* implies the dragon's hoard.

Comment: Actually the Greek for dragon was *drakon/dragon*, and they were seen as more serpentine than lizardlike (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons_in_Greek_mythology).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a sililarity in words, the passage of time can change the meanings and sounds of words. As noted above hoard and treasure translate to the word **thisavrós** in Greek. But this does this does not sound (IMO) like the word thesaurus (using Gogle translate).**Thisavros** has a potential suffix that sounds similar to **sávra**: Greek word for Lizard.

Accoding to (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnmcNPU4Hks) the ancient Egyptian God of *words/writing* is Thoth/ **Djehuty**. The lengthy sound ...*Deeeeeee.*... is said to originate from the sound made by an eagle swooping down from the sky/sun.The sun, back then, was worshiped as God and thus early man adopted the sound. Djehuty seems to have changed to **Deus** in Latin and **Theos/Theou** in Greek - the word for God.

Joining 'Theos' with 'Savros' creates a God-Lizard, a **Theosavros**. In addition the words 'Savvy and savoir, the latter being French for ***to know***, are closer to the sound of the Greek **sávra**. In the King James Bible John 1:1 the verse reads: In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.  Currently, the Thesaurus is described a collection of and knowledge of (God's) words.

Google's etymology of the word **savant** indicates an 'old' French origin of **savoir** or saveir, which itself originates from the Vulgar Latin ***sapēre**,“to taste”.
Thus using Google translate we have God, Knowledge (tree),wisdom and taste. Also, evil and apple share the word ***malum*** in Latin.

Alternatively, in Egypt, the snake symbol, or Uraeus, located on a Pharaoh’s headdress denoted great wisdom and God-like powers. Also, just about every religion around the world starts with a snake or serpent deity - See **Nagas** in India. These have gone on to morph into dragons:(Dragons, Serpents and Slayers, Daniel Ogden, 2013, and; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_worship. The Thesaurus literally becomes a book for the wisest: as equated with virtues of the snake, lizard or serpent.

Also, dragons,as dramatised in the film Jason and the Argonaut (with the Hydra), or as in the Garden of Hesperides *guarding orchards with one apple tree* were also described as protecting hoards of gold and treasure (in ancient times). The film shows one such treasure: a Golden Fleece. Others believe dinosaur fossils, which gave rise to the many fantastic legends, and precious metals and stones were often found together at a time when little was known about dinosaurs.

All information is from older books read over the years.

**Update:**
Albanian word for Treasure is **Thesar**

A collection of valuable things. Etymology: From **tresor**, from thesaurus, from θησαυρός. But, maybe from Albanian Thesar, **"thes"** (sack) and **"ar"** (gold). Any single thing that one values greatly. **Sack of gold?**

Sounds more plausible as a description of treasure than **thisavrós**

Also, since the nineteenth century, both countries have been separate nation-states, but for at least twenty-two centuries **Albania and Greece belonged to the same state** in various forms that it took
(https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=was+albania+part+of+greece).

Comment: There is, unfortunately, so much false etymology here it's difficult to know where to start. Please back up your answer with verifiable sources. (That *thesaurus* **can** be split into *theos+sauros* is much the same as asserting that the English word *determine* can be split into *deter+mine* to mean "persuade not to dig".)

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=thesaurus specifies athesaurus as meaning treasure but also argues for "No etymology, but probably a technical loanword, without a doubt from Pre-Greek."