# what is a word to describe a word-snob

Tags: meaning, pejorative-language

I can't think of the word that describes a word snob and use of the word pretty much proves you are one.  Anybody?

Comment: @TimLymington - I don't believe your link is a duplicate of the OP's question. Close, but not quite.

Comment: [Similar](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/whats-a-big-vocabulary-word-for-someone-with-a-big-vocabulary) perhaps your answer is here?

Comment: The OP is doing the ELU equivalent of the "Prince Albert in a Can" joke.

Answer (score 3):

Pedant: A person who is excessively concerned with minor details and rules or with displaying academic learning.