# A word or phrase to describe someone who is obsessed with words?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I want to be able to describe the love for, or obsession with, words. It may also be a condition from other's perspective.

It maybe because he is a lunatic who wants to aggrandize his vocabulary, a crazy person who can't forget the words he hears wafting around, or someone who wants to set a world record or something. Try fitting it in these:

> He is a _______ who can blurt a thousand synonyms for good.
>
> He is so ______ that he can be called a dictionary with a heartbeat.
>
> He is showing what a _____ he is.
>
> If thesaurus was a ghost, he would be dwelling in that _____'s body.

Any word or phrase would do.

Comment: Already checked. Unsatisfied.

Comment: It's a shame that "dictophile" is only a slang term; it seems to encompass the definition and connotations you're looking for.

Comment: If I needed a special word for a normal human being, I would suggest _Logovore_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I always thought chainsaws were logovores.

Comment: Perhaps *ELUer*?

Answer (score 3):

You can go with ***verbomaniac.*** Also, ***logomaniac*** is similar.

> *verbomania:* Obsession with words.
>
> *logomania:* Great enthusiasm for words.
>
> <sub>**Source:** http://en.wiktionary.org</sub>
>
> <sub>**Note:** Both words have the sense of excessive talking also.</sub>

If you want a more common phrase, you can use ***word buff***.

---

**Note:** There is also a similar question asked before: 
 [What's a big-vocabulary word for someone with a big vocabulary?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/whats-a-big-vocabulary-word-for-someone-with-a-big-vocabulary)

I'm giving different answers from there which are more related to obsession. For example; *logophile*, which is given as an answer in that question, comes to mind but *logomaniac* is closer to obsession.

Comment: I've always used *logorrhea* for *excessive* talking.

Answer (score 3):

I think [lexicomaniac](http://nws.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary/newword_display_alpha.php?letter=Le&last=60) may suggest an exaggerated love for words:

> (noun) : one who loves words and reading
>   [Its] book stock, which increases by about 8,000 volumes a year "a far cry from the 800 books that established Carlyle's home for the library's 800 original lexicomaniacs. —The Independent (London), October 26, 2005

Source: http://nws.merriam-webster.com

Answer (score 3):

**logophile** may be the best of the suggestions to date.

**word-lover** and **word buff** also seem to convey a fondness for words 
and their nuances.

**word fan** or **word fanatic** might suggest an excessive enthusiasm for words.

**logomaniac** suggests an insane and perhaps violent level of enthusiasm.

A name used by a member of Saundspel is **linguaphile**. 
This seems appropriate handle for a linguist or language lover.

Comment: This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.

Answer (score -1):

Lexophile describes person obsessed with words

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please consider improving your answer by citing a dictionary or other references.