# Is there a word for a person who loves to build his vocabulary?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What is the English word for a person who loves building his vocabulary?

Comment: Do you mean creating his own words? if yes I'd say ironically a "vocabulist".

Comment: Related, likely duplicate: [word for someone with large vocabulary](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/whats-a-big-vocabulary-word-for-someone-with-a-big-vocabulary). Would those words help here?

Comment: Vocabulist is the lexicographer,writer of vocabulary..Not a person who loves building his vocabulary.

Comment: Well, there's also *lexicomane* (indicates a mania) and *logophile* (lover of words). Bear in mind that English doesn't have a single word for everything, and sometimes you either have to use more than one, or shoehorn a literal meaning to fit.

Comment: Do you mean a person who enjoys learning the meanings of more and more words and expressions? Do you want only one-word answers?

Comment: How about 'tiresome'?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite term for this is a **wordsmith**, someone who demonstrates facility with words.

Answer (score 0):

I would call him a **"word-lover"**.

Of course there are terms such as **logophile** (one who appreciates and enjoys words) but they are not common enough and their meaning wouldn't be recognized in oridinary conversation. In the higher register, however, "logophile" would be more appropriate.

> logophile (noun) "One who appreciates and enjoys words." From the Greek λόγος (word, speech) + φίλος (friend, lover). [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/logophile)