# Is there a word for being addicted to words?

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't know... I just thought it might sound really pretty, or "deep" in some way. I've been compiling a list of beautiful and rare words and I'm pretty sure I am addicted to words so I thought "why not?". I would appreciate an answer, and thank you in advance!

Comment: @Silenus  Why post as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Other related questions: [What's a big-vocabulary word for someone with a big vocabulary?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12777), [Is there a word for a person who loves to build his vocabulary?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223589) Please read through the answers to these posts to see if any of the suggested words work for you. If they don't, please edit your post to explain in more detail the kind of word you want.