# What is the word for "knowledge of words?"

Tags: vocabulary

I remember that there was a word that meant being knowledgeable about many words, but I've forgotten what the word was.

Comment: Linguist is often used.

Comment: A linguist, @user116032,  is rather one who has learned about how languages work, and to what laws or regularities those workings tend to conform. I think the questioner is looking more for a word for the quality of having a huge vocabulary. Linguists may generally have above-average vocabularies, but that is not their defining quality.

Comment: Disagree (but good point).  You can be guaranteed a linguist has a huge vocabulary.  I'll lurk and see what comes up.

Comment: @user116032 Just because lions have tails, and elephants have tails, does not mean lions are elephants. *Linguist* is no more suitable than *lawyer* or *doctor* or *professor*.

Comment: @user116032 No you're wrong, there's no guarantee at all that a linguist has a huge vocabulary.

Comment: Change guaranteed to probably.  Probably is good enough for most of life.

Comment: Depending on how one finds out about this big vocabulary, 'eloquence' might be a good word to describe the trait.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/whats-a-big-vocabulary-word-for-someone-with-a-big-vocabulary) may be of use. Here are some of the words suggested from it: "**lexicomane**, **sesquipedalian**, **vocabularian**, **logophile**". Their specific definitions are listed in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The OED has **verbalist**:

> 2. One who is skilled in the use or knowledge of words.
>
> 1794   T. Taylor tr. Pausanias Descr. Greece I. Pref. p. viii,   His
>   meaning is, frequently, on this account, inaccessible to the most
>   consummate verbalists.
>
> 1822   T. Taylor tr. Apuleius Metamorphosis 351
>   This blunder of the editor, who was otherwise a good verbalist, is a
>   deplorable specimen of ignorance in things of the greatest importance.
>
> 1860–1   Philol. Soc. Trans. 164   The opinion of the best English
>   verbalist I ever knew.